# How do I force symbols to be grouped together?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

In a book I'm reading they use symbols prefixed with * as extensions of functions/operations/relations/sets, e.g. *≤ extends ≤, *A extends A and so on.

Now, I want to use those extended operators in formulas, e.g.:

```
a *≤ b
A ∈ *A
```

My question is: How do I force the `*` and the other operator together?

When I write `*` as `$^*$`, the grouping doesn't reliably work, even if I try to force it by using brackets, it's still messed up.

So, how do I force symbols reliably together?

Finally, here are some examples:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try one of these solutions:

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand\sleq{\mathrel{{}^*\!{\leq}}}
\newcommand\ssleq{\mathrel{\prescript{*}{}\!{\leq}}}
\newcommand\pst[1]{{}^{*\mkern-1.5mu}#1}
\newcommand\psst[1]{\prescript{*\mkern-1.5mu}{}#1}

\begin{document}

\[ a \sleq b, \quad A\in\pst{V}\]%
\[ a \ssleq b, \quad A\in\psst{V} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How might this setup be generalized to handle `*V`, etc?

Comment: @Mico: I've added an example code. I can see you and me often use the same math kerning :o)

Answer (score 5):

You could set up a macro called `\xtnd` to "extend" a symbol by prefixing a raised asterisk to it. The default "math type" of the "extended" symbol is set to "mathrel". If that's not appropriate, provide optional arguments such as `ord` or `bin` to set the math type of the newly created symbol to "mathord" and "mathbin", respectively.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "align*" env.
\newcommand\ext[2][rel]{\csname math#1\endcsname{{{}^*}\mkern-1.5mu{#2}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&a \ext{\le} b\\            % "\le" is of type "mathrel"
&A \in \ext[ord]{V}\\       % letter "V" is of type mathord 
&A \in \ext[ord]{\mkern-5mu A} % "A" needs more neg. kerning than "V" does
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```